# JPA/toplink heterogeneous list of entities

Tags: java, orm, jpa, polymorphism, toplink

Colleagues,
Using JPA I need resolve following issue: at database level exits 3 entities (saying SuperEntity, DetailsAEntity and DetailsBEntity). SuperEntity contains common part of fields for DetailsAEntity and DetailsBEntity.

So the question: is it possible to resolve collection of mixed elements DetailsAEntity and DetailsBEntity from JPA? May be exits some extension in toplink to specify class for entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming SuperEntity is mapped as the root of the inheritance tree then the result of queries for this type can return a heterogeneous collection of its concrete subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Queries are polymorphic in standard JPA. Here are the relevant sections from the JPA 1.0 Specification:

> #### 3.6.5 Polymorphic Queries
>
> By default, all queries are
>   polymorphic. That is, the FROM clause
>   of a query designates not only
>   instances of the specific entity
>   class(es) to which it explicitly
>   refers, but subclasses as well. The
>   instances returned by a query include
>   instances of the subclasses that
>   satisfy the query conditions.
>
> For example, the query
>
> ```
> select avg(e.salary) from Employee e where e.salary > 80000
> ```
>
> returns the average salary of all
>   employees, including subtypes of
>   `Employee`, such as `Manager` and
>   `Exempt`.

And

> #### 4.4.8 Polymorphism
>
> Java Persistence queries are
>   automatically polymorphic. The FROM
>   clause of a query designates not only
>   instances of the specific entity
>   class(es) to which explicitly refers
>   but of subclasses as well. The
>   instances returned by a query include
>   instances of the subclasses that
>   satisfy the query criteria.

So any query on a supertype will include subtypes in the results by default.

Comment: It is clear, but is not an answer to my question. I didn't ask if it possible, I have asked how to do it. Copypaste of spec "The instances returned by a query include instances of the subclasses that satisfy the query criteria" - doesn't shows me how to do it. avg - retursn number, but i need 2 types of objects in the collection

Comment: @Dewfy I'm sorry if you didn't find it helpful but I think it does answer the question (just do a query on a type) and the spec even provides an example (*returns the average salary of all employees, including subtypes of Employee, such as Manager and Exempt*). This also clarifies that this is standard JPA, which was my main goal. If you don't find it helpful, maybe other readers will.